# Fabric - Data encryption

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Is it possible to encrypt the data directly inside the chaincode?

What I'm trying to do is to hide data between participants without using the channels.

For example:

- The network have three participants A,B,C
- The chaincode holds the public key of B which is used to encrypt the data.
- A and C send data to the chaincode which store the data encrypted with the public key of B.
- B with his private key can decrypt the data retrieved.

Is this way a secure way to encrypt the data? Could work?
 Thanks.

Comment: you can use the concept of private data for this : https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/private-data/private-data.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Fabric example for symmetric key encryption, see the [doc](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/chaincode4ade.html?#chaincode-encryption) and an [example](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/release-1.3/examples/chaincode/go/enccc_example).

A similar mechanism could also be used for asymmetric encryption as you propose. However you may want to encrypt the data on the client side, and then pass the encrypted data into the chaincode.

Alternatively, you could use the private data feature to pass the private data to peers of authorized organizations. The other organizations would only receive a hash of the private data in the block transaction. For more details see the private data [documentation](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.3/private-data/private-data.html).

Comment: I'm also interested in the idea of encrypting data in fabric. I noticed the encryption doc and examples were removed with fabtic version 2.0. Does anyone know why?